# Transactional Support in Spring Data Elastic Search

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working with Spring Data Elasticsearch , Spring Data has support for Transactional queries .

This i am enabling by @Transactional annotation.

But since elasticsearch does not have any ACID properties what does this Transactional do, the documentation itself is not clear about this

Answer (score 1):

On Spring Data Elasticsearch, it does nothing. It's an annotation from Spring Data Commons, but not all stores support all attributes and features from that.